# Quorum - Implement Hybrid Casper FFG / Proof of Stake?

Tags: quorum

After Ethereum rolls out Hybrid Casper FFG / Proof of Stake in the Serenity release, will Quorum follow suit to incorporate Hybrid Casper FFG / Proof of Stake as another consensus algorithm? (on top of IBFT, Raft)

Answer (score 1):

Quorum project has a set of people responsible for merging upstream changes coming in from geth project. As geth rolls out features, these features will propagate into Quorum and this includes PoA/PoS consensus algorithms. Additionally, Quorum team welcomes input and modifications into our own repositories, in fact, IBFT implementation was a contribution from Amis team.